# LocationProvider enabled check

Tags: android, geolocation

Im confused how i can check if an LocationProvider is enabled or not.
In an APP i need to show some kind of message that the user should turn on location services.
On my Nexus 5 testing device with location turned OFF is still get true back on GPS. In the System Setting "Location" i can see "Location OFF".

```
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try
    {

        final boolean gpsProviderEnabled = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

While searching about this problem i found this solution also

```
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
```

There i get an empty String back which seem ok in that situation as the Location is turned off

I just think whats the best approach to find out if location is on/off on System ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks if location provider is enabled or not and it also throws an alert to take the user to the settings screen to turn on GPS.

```
 LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

     buildAlertMessageNoGps();

    } else {

     //Location provider is on
    }



private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
  final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setMessage(
    "Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(
         @SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog,
         @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
        startActivity(new Intent(
          android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

       }
      })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
       @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
      dialog.cancel();

     }
    });
  final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
 }
```

Comment: Thats exacly whats confusing me, i turned GPS and all other OFF and still get TRUE back when manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) is invoked

Comment: Try closing your application and opening it again after you change GPS setting. Sometimes there may be a delay in noticing the updating setting. Ideally that should not return true if GPS is turned off. I am using the above code in our application and it works fine. Did you test it on any other device?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the function onProviderEnabled or onProviderDisabled, you can check whether your gps provider is turn on or not

```
    public class LocationTest extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager = null;
    String best;
    TextView output;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_test);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        log("location provider:");
        dumpProvider();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        best = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        log("Best provider: " + best);
        Location location;
         location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("network");
        dumpLocation(location);

        location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
        dumpLocation(location);

        location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("passive");
        dumpLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        dumpLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        log("\nProvider enabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        log("\nProvider disabled: " + provider);
    }

    public void dumpLocation(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            log("unknow location");
        } else {
            log(location.toString());
        }

    }

    public void log(String data) {
        output.append(data + "\n");
    }

    public void dumpProvider() {
        List<String> provider = locationManager.getAllProviders();
        for (Iterator<String> i = provider.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            log((String) i.next());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 15000, 1, this);
    }
}
```